# An increasing bounded map $f$ is such that $f'\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**The question.**

Let $f$ be a differentiable map $\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ such that

- $\forall x\geqslant0,\quad f'>0$
- $\exists M>0,\quad \forall x\geqslant0,\quad f(x)\leqslant M$.

> Does there exist $f$ verifying such conditions such that $f'(x)$ does not tend to $0$ when $x$ goes to infinity?

**What I tried.**

I think the answer is **yes** because of the following.

I tought about a function $f'$ doing something resembling to $x\mapsto \frac 1{1+x^2}$, but with little peaks like this:

[image]

This function would not have a limit when $x\to\infty$, and $f$ would still be bounded.

**Final questions.**

Does this idea works? Can you formalise it? Am I totally wrong here?

Comment: Duplicate of several duplicates...

Comment: f'(3/4) doesn't look positive

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I know, but I had no better image. But I explain it in details in the question...

Comment: Also, you might want to purchase Hauchecorne, *Les Contre-Exemples en Mathématiques*

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Actually I should have it somewhere ! :) I will look up there.